# Unity fill amount lerp returning wrong value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fill, lerp

Trying to lerp the fill amount of a health bar.

**Have this code:**

```
public float lerpSpeed = 2;
public void FillBar()
{
    bar.fillAmount = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 0.7f, Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed);
    Debug.Log(emotion.fillAmount);
}
```

When the function runs, after a click event, the bar.fillAmount goes only to 0.28

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is a little sparce on the details. But the reason you are not getting past 0.28 is because the third parameter of Mathf.Lerp represents

> The interpolation value between the two floats.

So to get the right amount, you need to set a variable and update the value in it each time you fill the bar, preferably in something like a coroutine or in the update loop.

```
public float lerpSpeed = 2;
private float t = 0;

public void FillBar()
{
    bar.fillAmount = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 0.7f, t);
    t += Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed
}
```

Comment: Using Time.deltaTime shouldnt have the same result? All the code samples Ive looked into were using `Time.deltaTime * lerpSpeed` as a Lerp parameter and their code was running smoothly

Comment: He used `Time.deltaTime` updating the t already? This is the correct way to lerp.